# Exception Requirements on Standard Containers

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

C++11 §23.2.1.10 specifies:

> Unless otherwise specified all container types defined
>   in this Clause meet the following additional requirements:
>
> - if an exception is thrown by an insert() or emplace() function while    inserting a single element, that function has no effects.
> - no erase() , clear() , pop_back() or pop_front() function throws an    exception.

Regarding the first bullet point, How does the container guarantee that?
The constructor for `T` might have side-effects. Should it not be "***has no effect on the container***"

Regarding the second bullet point, This normally calls `allocator::deallocate(T*,size_t)` which is not `noexcept`. Why should eventual exceptions be masked away?

Comment: Determined the standard you're asking about by matching up the text.

Comment: Wouldn't these questions be better off on `std-discussion`?

Comment: So I would read 1) charitably as 'has no effects beyond what are produced by the embedded type constructors'.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : what changed in ' 14?

Comment: @sp2danny Another bullet point about `push_back()`, `push_front()`, `emplace_back()`, and `emplace_front()`.

Comment: @sp2danny: It moved, is as close as I looked. Feel free to check it out yourself.

Comment: `deallocate()` is required to not throw exceptions.

Comment: @T.C. : can't find that in the standard. could you provide a quote?

Comment: Look for `deallocate` in the allocator requirements table ([allocator.requirements])

Comment: Presumably the item must be constructed before the `insert` or `emplace` begins execution? If the copy or move constructor is invoked, maybe there's a statement elsewhere in the standard to cover that case under "unless otherwise specified".

Comment: Here's a thought: if the container ends up invoking a copy constructor of an object, I thought that the standard makes no guarantees about any "global" side effects of copy constructors happening / not happening. Because, this is the legal hole that permits unlimited copy elision. So if your program is such that there are externally visible side effects of e.g. `std::vector` copying your objects around I would have assumed anyways that the standard makes no guarantees about whether those happen

Comment: (Also @LightnessRacesinOrbit ) : Maybe someone can think of a better title for this...

Comment: There are many places in the standard where it doesn't quite mean "no effects whatsoever, anywhere" when it says "no effects".  The `uninitialized_meow` functions, for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Table 28 specifies one of the requirements of an allocator is that `deallocate()` "Does not throw exceptions". That is how the standard can make the assertion about `erase()`, `clear()`, `pop_back()` and `pop_front()`